# Interpreting the graph of the following confidence interval for the proportion of binomial in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, interpretation

```
 #Recursion of Binomial

  bino <- function(n,p){
       px <- (1-p)^n
       X <- 0
       Fx <- px
       U <- runif(1)
       while(Fx<U){
          X<- X+1
          px <- ((n-X+1)*p*px)/(X*(1-p))
          Fx <- Fx+ px
       }
       return(X)
    }

    #inputs 
    N <- 10000
    n <- 10
    p <- 0.7

    set.seed(100)
    X <- rep(0,N)

    for(i in 1:N) X[i]=bino(n,p)

    phat <- rep(0,n+1)

    for(i in 0:n)phat[i+1]=(sum(X==i))/N

    phat.CI <- 1.96*sqrt(phat*(1-phat)/N)


    # plot output

    plot(0:n, dbinom(0:n, n, p), type="h", xlab="x", ylab="p(x)")
    points(0:n, phat+phat.CI, pch=3)
    points(0:n, phat-phat.CI, pch=3)
```

*observing the graph it is seen that the interval for the proportion when X=10 is wider than that of others. What does it indicate?*

After running the code here is the graph:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us what you would have expected to see after running your code?  What exactly were you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @BabakP I think the graph indicates that as $p=0.7$ so it is more likely to get the number of success higher. So the  interval of proportion of getting higher success is wider to give better confidence. Is that the matter?

Comment: In your question you state: "observing the graph it is seen that the interval for the proportion when X=10 is wider than that of others. What does it indicate?" Which to me does not look true from the above graph, and secondly you state now $p=0.7$ in your above comment.  So which value are we actually interested in discussing, $p=.7$ or $X=10$ or ?